# Optimization tricks when variables in the denominator?

Tags: regression, optimization

I wonder if I have any hopes to solve the following optimization question: 
$$
\arg\min_{\beta}\dfrac{||y-X\beta||_2^2}{v^Tv+\beta^TA^TA\beta-(c+v^TA\beta)^2} + \lambda||\beta||_1
$$
where $\beta$ is a $p \times 1$ vector. $y$ and $v$ are $n \times 1$, $X$ and $A$ are $n \times p$, and $c$ and $\lambda$ are scalars.

I don't even know what I should read to solve this problem other than directly taking the derivative. Could anyone please help suggest some techniques?

We don't have to add the term $\lambda ||\beta||_1$, but it seems discarding this penalty term does not make the problem any easier. Thanks.

Comment: It really is a shame that techniques from automatic differentiation still seem to be largely unknown in the statistical community. Using software like AD Model Builder you can write code to solve a problem like this in an hour or so and never have to write anything involving derivatives.

Comment: @davefournier Thanks, but I barely use them because they are slow. (not sure why the rest statistical community ignores them though.)

Comment: @Haohan Wang   Actually for a problem like this it is usually much faster than writing the code for the derivatives by hand, because in this case reverse mode automatic differentiation involves only about 4 times the calculataions needed for the function itself. If you have a data set I to fit can write the code for the model to demonstate how fast it is.

Comment: @HaohanWang Could you provide some motivation for considering this objective function? Thanks!

Comment: @Ben, sorry but it's part of my project and I have this term after I simplify the original cost function. I am not sure that I am allowed to share the original idea here because it might involve some novelty we are trying and I am not the one who initiates this project. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: @davefournier I see. When I tried with those tools, it's usually much slower when there are constraints in the cost function. I will try then if it's both convenient and fast. (Then I don't understand why people still spend time learning optimization tricks.) Thanks.